Does the use of OPRF or OT remove the need of HE in PSI?
I was reading a systematic literature review on Private Set Intersection (PSI) protocols (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1574013723000345#sec8), which mentions that the main implementations of PSI often use Homomorphic Encryption (HE), Oblivious Pseudorandom Function (OPRF), or Oblivious Transfer (OT). However, it seems like the author discusses these techniques as separate implementations. My question is: Does the use of OPRF or OT in PSI protocols eliminate the need for a HE scheme, or are there scenarios where HE is still necessary despite using OPRF or OT?

Yes, given an OPRF or an OT scheme, you can design a PSI scheme without having to use homomorphic encryption. In fact, most state-of-the-art schemes do not use HE at all, because it is much slower than using OPRFs.
